# Combining several matrices into a single matrix — Is this possible?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, markov-chains

Here is a following example I thought of involving Discrete Time Markov Chains.

Throughout this system, there are two pairs of states : (State A, State B) and (State 1, State 2).

There are 3 stages : Stage 1, Stage 2 and Stage 3. All probabilities across all stages and all chains are unique (i.e. apostrophe ' notation to signify unique).

Remember that all row sums in any matrix must sum to 1 (since these are probabilities).

- **Stage 1:**

At the start of Stage 1, a Markov Chain tells you the (fixed) probability of transition between State A and State B:

$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
P_{aa} & P_{ab} \\
P_{ba} & P_{bb}
\end{bmatrix}$$

- **Stage 2:**

At the start of Stage 2, a Markov Chain tells you the (fixed)  probability of transition between State 1 and State 2 if you were in State A at Stage 1 ... and a Markov Chain tells you the (fixed)  probability of transition between State 1 and State 2 if you were in State B at Stage 1:

$$P_{|a} = \begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} \\
p_{21} & p_{22}
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$P_{|b} = \begin{bmatrix}
p_{'11} & p_{'12} \\
p_{'21} & p_{'22}
\end{bmatrix}$$

- **Stage 3:**

At the start of Stage 3, a Markov Chain tells you the (fixed)  probability of transition between State A and State B if you were in State 1 at Stage 2 ... and a Markov Chain tells you the (fixed)  probability of transition between State A and State B if you were in State 2 at Stage 2

$$P_{|1a} = \begin{bmatrix}
P_{'aa} & P_{'ab} \\
P_{'ba} & P_{'bb}
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$P_{|1b} = \begin{bmatrix}
P_{''aa} & P_{''ab} \\
P_{''ba} & P_{''bb}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Thus, this system captures a sort of "feedback loop". A person cycles between Stage 1, Stage 2, Stage 3 - and then restarts at Stage 1.

**My Question:** Is it possible to represent this entire 3 Stage system into a single Markov Chain (i.e. single transition matrix)? Or is this fundamentally impossible?

Thanks!

- **Note 1:** I am thinking I could either model this as a Second Order Markov Chain (i.e. transition probabilities for next state depend on current state and previous state) .... or as Markov Chain where the transition probabilities change with time (e.g. non-homogenous discrete time Markov Chain)?
- **Note 2:** A visualization of this system that I made

[image]

Comment: How do you determine which state you are in in the first two stages - do you mean you have a fixed number of transition steps and observe the resulting state? If yes, you have a fix probability of reaching a certain state (the $n$-th power of the transition matrix) and thus this will help you to form the initial distribution before stage 3. Or you can force them to form a big, block like transition matrix incorporating all transition matrices.

Comment: You can definitely model this as a single Markov chain - you just need more states, so that the state includes the stage information. If I understand your description correctly, this means you'll have a total of $3\times2\times2=12$ states. The transition matrix will have a lot of zeros.

Comment: thank you everyone for your replies! Does my "Note 1" make sense (i.e. second order markov chain)?