# Can a Feedback Loop be Modelled as a Markov Chain?

Tags: probability

Consider the followings example:

- A randomly selected person in the population can be either "healthy" or "sick" with some given probabilities
- In the "near" future - if a person is "healthy", they have a certain probability of being "employed" vs being "unemployed". If a person is "sick", they have a certain probability of being "employed" vs being "unemployed" (i.e. its harder to work you have long term medical conditions)
- In the "distant" future - if a person is "employed", they have a certain probability of being "healthy" or "sick". If a person is "unemployed", they have a certain probability of being "healthy" or "sick" (i.e. perhaps working a lot can worsen your health).
- Beyond this, we say that the effect of the previous "feedback" dies off and becomes negligible (i.e. "memoryless" beyond 2 transitions)

Thus, a 2-level "feedback loop" can be created to describe the interactions between "health" and "employment".

**My Question:** Is it possible to represent this idea as a (2nd Order) Discrete Time Markov Chain?

For example, I could write the State Space of this problem as:

$$
S = \{[(H_{t-2}, E_{t-1}), (E_{t-1}, H_t)], [(H_{t-2}, E_{t-1}), (E_{t-1}, S_t)], [(H_{t-2}, U_{t-1}), (U_{t-1}, H_t)], [(H_{t-2}, U_{t-1}), (U_{t-1}, S_t)], [(S_{t-2}, E_{t-1}), (E_{t-1}, H_t)], [(S_{t-2}, E_{t-1}), (E_{t-1}, S_t)], [(S_{t-2}, U_{t-1}), (U_{t-1}, H_t)], [(S_{t-2}, U_{t-1}), (U_{t-1}, S_t)]\}
$$

As an example, $[(H_{t-2}, E_{t-1}), (E_{t-1}, H_t)]$ would mean:

- $H_{t-2}$ = Healthy at time $t-2$
- $E_{t-1}$ = Employed at time $t-1$
- $H_t$ = Healthy at time $t$

Next, based on this State Space, transition probabilities can be written as:

$$
P_{ij,k} = P [  (S_t = k) |  (S_{t-1} = j,  S_{t-2} =  i )  ]
$$

where:

- $P_{ij,k}$ is the transition probability of going to state $k$ (at time t) from state $j$  (at time t-1) from state $i$ (at time t-2)
- $S_t = k_t$ is the state at time $t$,
- $S_{t-1} = j_{t-1}$ is the state at time $t-1$, and
- $S_{t-2} = i_{t-2}$ is the state at time $t-2$.

Thus, all together:

- State 1: $[(H_{t-2}, E_{t-1}), (E_{t-1}, H_t)]$
- State 2: $[(H_{t-2}, E_{t-1}), (E_{t-1}, S_t)]$
- State 3: $[(H_{t-2}, U_{t-1}), (U_{t-1}, H_t)]$
- State 4: $[(H_{t-2}, U_{t-1}), (U_{t-1}, S_t)]$
- State 5: $[(S_{t-2}, E_{t-1}), (E_{t-1}, H_t)]$
- State 6: $[(S_{t-2}, E_{t-1}), (E_{t-1}, S_t)]$
- State 7: $[(S_{t-2}, U_{t-1}), (U_{t-1}, H_t)]$
- State 8: $[(S_{t-2}, U_{t-1}), (U_{t-1}, S_t)]$

And the corresponding transition matrix P would then be:

$$
P = 
\begin{bmatrix}
P_{11,1} & P_{11,2} & P_{11,3} & P_{11,4} & P_{11,5} & P_{11,6} & P_{11,7} & P_{11,8} \\
P_{12,1} & P_{12,2} & P_{12,3} & P_{12,4} & P_{12,5} & P_{12,6} & P_{12,7} & P_{12,8} \\
P_{13,1} & P_{13,2} & P_{13,3} & P_{13,4} & P_{13,5} & P_{13,6} & P_{13,7} & P_{13,8} \\
P_{14,1} & P_{14,2} & P_{14,3} & P_{14,4} & P_{14,5} & P_{14,6} & P_{14,7} & P_{14,8} \\
P_{15,1} & P_{15,2} & P_{15,3} & P_{15,4} & P_{15,5} & P_{15,6} & P_{15,7} & P_{15,8} \\
P_{16,1} & P_{16,2} & P_{16,3} & P_{16,4} & P_{16,5} & P_{16,6} & P_{16,7} & P_{16,8} \\
P_{17,1} & P_{17,2} & P_{17,3} & P_{17,4} & P_{17,5} & P_{17,6} & P_{17,7} & P_{17,8} \\
P_{18,1} & P_{18,2} & P_{18,3} & P_{18,4} & P_{18,5} & P_{18,6} & P_{18,7} & P_{18,8} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**Thus, is the approach that I described a valid way to describe a 2-layer feedback loop between (healthy, sick), (employed, unemployed) and again (healthy, sick)?**

Thanks!

- Note: I think I could use Maximum Likelihood Estimation based on the Multinomial Probability Distribution to estimate these transition probabilities. For each person in the dataset, I would isolate all pairs for the same $(i,j)$ states, and then see how many went to each unique $k$ state. I would then divide the second calculation by the first calculation to obtain the sample estimates of the transition probabilities.

**References:**

- [Combining several matrices into a single matrix — Is this possible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4832384/combining-several-matrices-into-a-single-matrix-is-this-possible)